# Python opencv/cv2 mis-colorations

Tags: python, opencv

Example image :
[image: Example image]

I'm working on a project in Python with OpenCV where I need to fade the colors of an image a little to make it darker. Things have been going ok so far except that I'm getting weird mis-colorations in the resulting image where large areas are either white or purple or similar. See the attached example. I can't find any explanation for this even after extensive Googling. Any ideas what might be causing this?

My code looks like this:

```
poster = stbt.load_image("test1.png")
b, g, r = cv2.split(poster)
val = 40
b -= val
g -= val
r -= val
poster = cv2.merge((b, g, r))
cv2.imshow("frame2", poster)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Looks like underflow -- i guess you subtract without saturation, but since you didn't show your code, it's rather difficult to tell you what exactly you've done wrong.

Comment: You should use gamma correction in order to avoid mis-coloration. Example: [https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/05/opencv-gamma-correction/](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/05/opencv-gamma-correction/)

Comment: Please, [edit] your question, rather that posting unformatted code in a comment.

Comment: Sorry about that:) Please see the code and image example

Comment: you can always use [subtract](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#subtract) from OpenCV, it will do the saturation for you and you can pass a scalar...  and you do not need to do split or merge. Also, you may try as well gamma correction as in the answer from @Mika72

Comment: You can try the same approach in HSV color space but for any one channel!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I've tried a lot of things including the suggestions above. I did manage to get rid of the miscolorations but still couldn't get quite the result I wanted. However I found this https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/index.html which looks like it should be able to do the trick for me.

Edit:
I tested the above solution and it worked fine :). See example below:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

img = Image.open("dev/poster.png")
br = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)
img = br.enhance(0.7)
img.show("")
```

Comment: can you share the solution?